# Proper Thymeleaf input form to store LocalDateTime

Tags: java, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I'm trying to store LocalDateTime in Thymeleafe form, but with no success. What I have for now:

Model:

```
public class Example{
    ...
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;
    ...
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/saveExample")
public String saveOrUpdate(@Valid @ModelAttribute("example") Example example, BindingResult bindingResult) {
```

Form:

```
<input type="date" th:field="*{creationDate}"/>
```

Error that I'm getting:

```
[Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime' for property 'creationDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.persistence.Column java.time.LocalDateTime] for value '2020-01-17'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2020-01-17]]
```

I've tried lots of different solution from google, but with no luck. Any suggestions?
Best regards.

Comment: Do you have `thymeleaf-extras-java8time` in your pom.xml?  What exceptions do you see?

Comment: Yes - I have this dependency in my pom. Error message in post.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at using a `Converter`:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56565496/spring-boot-2-1-5-failed-to-convert-property-value-of-type-java-lang-string-to-r

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to parse value *'2020-01-17'*, but it's not a valid value for **LocalDateTime** class.

Possible solutions:

1. Use **LocalDate** instead of **LocalDateTime** in your model class
2. Use **String** instead of **LocalDateTime** in your model class, then (in some service class, by example), parse your String value using own DateTimeFormatter:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
        .toFormatter();

    LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-01-17", formatter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `@DateTimeFormat` annotation to LocalDateTime fields in your entity. For example:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDateTime creationDate;
```